# Lucene MultiValue grouping on MultiValueField

Tags: java, lucene

I have a tree structure of documents, with a document having multiple parents.
This is mapped in the Lucene index using a multivaluefield when indexing as so:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new Field("uuid","value",MYFIELDTYPE.NOTANALYZED);
doc.add(new Field("parent","parent",MYFIELDTYPE.NOTANALYZED);
doc.add(new Field("parent","parent",MYFIELDTYPE.NOTANALYZED);
......
indexwriter.addDocument(doc)
```

I then need to group the results I get having the most common parent of the tree as my final result. I am facing a problem as the parent field contains only the direct parent, this direct parent is stored also in the index in the same way but when collecting the documents I don't know how to access it within the `collect(ind docID)`
I can access the fields and group through inserting into a map but how do a group for example if two elements within a group have the same parent. Also if a change to the index would be welcome

the Tree could look like this

```
                 Root1(Field1,UUID,parent)           Root2(Field,UUID,parent)
                 /                    \               /          \
                /                      \             /            \
             child1(content,           child2(content,          child3(content
             UUID,parent)              UUID,parent)             UUID,parent)
             /          \
            /            \
       child4(content,    child5(content,
       UUID,parent)       UUID, parent)
```

This is very small tree example but the tree would have more children. If for example the hit of the Query which is directed to the content field gets me that both 4,5,and 2 are hits then I would like to get Root1 as the result with all 1,2,4,5 in the group.

Comment: Please add an example tree and an example query (with our expected result).

Comment: @KarstenR. I added the example and a expected result.